# U"" literal for hardcoded literals in std::u32string issue

Tags: c++, c++17, utf

I want to quickly make "alert" animation draft with cocos2dx with Unicode symbols involved.

I'm using MSVS on Windows 11, cocos2dx 3.17, using `std::u32string` to store symbols.

My source file is encoded with codepage 65001 (UTF8 without signature).

I noticed I see some glitchy symbols that I don't use. For example:

```cpp
std::u32string test = U"Ö";
```

`test` will contain `"Ã–"`.

Further investigation gave me this result:

```
// bug - "Ã–" on screen and debug view
std::u32string u32TextBlankB = U"Ö";
// Ok - "Ö" on screen and debug view
std::u32string u32TextBlank = U"\x000000D6";
```

I have no clue why it works like this. Is it a compiler bug, or a misunderstanding of the concept?

Comment: Did you pass `/utf-8` to compiler flags?

Comment: You said your source file is encoded as UTF-8, so `U"Ö"` is physically stored on disk as `U"Ã–"`. If you don't tell the compiler that the file is encoded as UTF-8, it won't interpret the UTF-8 correctly to produce the proper symbols. You don't have this problem when using `U"\x..."` instead.

Comment: no, i didn't  pass `/utf8` cause we always load text from files)
Thanks for the comment and detailed explanation.